# Programmatically render an image of a silverlight control and save it to disk

Tags: silverlight, image, render

My asp.net website has a silverlight application.

For clients that do not have silverlight, I would like to serve alternate content.

The alternate content should include a static image of a silverlight control.

Server-side, I would like to programmatically render an image of the silverlight control and save it to disk. How can this be done?

Here is example code that may go into the Page_Load method:

```
if (!clientHasSilverlight()) {
    hideSilverLightObject();
    CustomSilverLightControl customSilverLightControl = new CustomSilverLightControl();
    customSilverLightControl.setProperties(properties);
    string fileName = renderControlAndSaveToTempFile(customSilverLightControl);
    Literal l = new Literal();
    l.Text = @"<img src=""" + fileName + @""" />";
    Page.Controls.Add(l);
}
```

Failing this, how may I create a control (in a separate assembly) that can be used by the silverlight application but which can also be used by the server-side code for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to run Silverlight embedded within an ASP.NET application, so there will be no `CustomSilverLightControl` that you've put in your code sketch above.  The best you can hope for would be running Silverlight within a child process, but that is highly likely to be slow and be a significant drain on resources.

A Silverlight application can take a screenshot of itself, and that's not too difficult to do.  Getting the screenshot out of Silverlight is harder, though, because of Silverlight running within the browser plugin.  You'd also have to modify your Silverlight application to support this screenshot-taking functionality and be able to hide it from regular users.

I fear it would be a lot of effort to modify your Silverlight application to support this screenshot-taking behaviour, and to set up the palaver required to start up your Silverlight application, get it to take a screenshot of itself, and then send the screenshot back to your web application.  Given the inevitable performance problems this approach would cause, I honestly can't see that this effort would be worth it.

Comment: Thanks Luke. In response, I added a little to the original question above.

Comment: @bboyle1234: the quick answer to your additional question is 'you can't'.  Silverlight uses a completely different version of the .NET Framework to ASP.NET, so you can't use the same control in both.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this on the `Page_Load`.

In your HTML/ASPX you'll have something like the following:

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
    <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightApplication1.xap"/>
    <param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError" />
    <param name="background" value="white" />
    <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
    <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style: none"/>
    </a>
</object>
```

The relevant bit is the the `<a href...` that is used, when Silverlight isn't present, to allow the user to go and install the plugin.

By default this displays the image at `http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=161376`:

[image: Install Silverlight image]

Replace this by your image that you've designed or captured from a machine that is running your application. This should let the user know that they don't have Silverlight installed and need to install it so a screen shot will have to be modified in some way.

For your case of the user viewing the site on an iPhone the screen shot would have to include the fact that iPhone users can't install Silverlight.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your time in making this answer. I am definitely hoping not to have another machine or process running a silverlight application just for generating these static images. Putting the image in that link is handy. Thanks for the tip, I'll use it for sure.

Comment: I am looking for a solution for users like iPhone users who can't install Silverlight.

Comment: @bboyle1234 - you've missed my point. You don't make the image on the fly. It's a static image you only need to create once. You can't run the Silverlight application on the server and have it serve images to the client.